# encode sound wave to image and text in Python?

Tags: python, image, audio

So i wrote the following code which converts an image input to a sound wave output and it works just fine.

```
import wave

try:
    #change the file's name and format
    image_file = 'image.png'
    fin = open(image_file, "rb") #binary read
    data = fin.read()
    fin.close()
except IOError:
    print("Image file %s not found" % imageFile)
    raise SystemExit

#Give the name for wav file produced at run time corresponding to the input file
sound_output = wave.open('image.wav', 'w')
sound_output.setparams((2, 2, 44100, 10, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))

hex_str = bytes(data) #convert binary data to string of bytes
sound_output.writeframes(hex_str)


sound_output.close()
```

Now i want to use that output wave sound and convert it back to image and text (not the original image but any image it can output). I'm thinking of the same approach that i use above which takes the wave sound file as input and read it as binary data. But then i don't know how to save that binary data as an image format (jpg or png) and a string of text. Anyone can help?

Comment: What is “image” about the file you read? Essentially, you could have any kind of “random” data, and the fact that it's a image file does not matter for this process, does it?

Comment: As @Anaphory has said, you have not read an image here, you have read the whole file, including the header and any other metadata. If the wav file is uncompressed, you should be able to turn it back into the same string of bytes that you made it from (i.e. the same steps, but backwards).

Comment: but what function should I use to output the image file?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: take the sound file input and read it as binary data, save that binary data as image file (ie: .bmp)

Comment: How do you establish the dimension of the output based on the wave file ? Number of samples and amplitude, maybe ? Also, what do you mean by "convert it back to text" ? What kind of "text", ascii version of the .wav ? Also, what do you mean by "not the original image but any it can output" ? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a structured format; convert to a bitmap format to produce an arbitrary image out of a lump of bits. But then just switching the filename extension from .wav to .bmp would accomplish the same thing; no actual conversion is useful or necessary ... except you probably want to tack on a small header with metadata (sample rate etc for sound; rectangle dimensions for an image). For "text" you don't even need that.

Comment: you mean i just replace the .wav to .bmp in this line of code?
 sound_output = wave.open('image.wav', 'w')

i'm confused, the function wave.open() is used for sound only right?

Comment: The `wave` library is what adds the metadata. Find -- or create -- a similar set of functions for writing bitmap images. For pure text, the generic `open` would suffice.